# .z suffix would get '406 Not Acceptable' error in restful web service

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, restful-url

I have a rest uri like `http://127.0.0.1:9000/users/{username}` based on spring MVC.

If I assign `x@y.com` or `x@y.a` to `{username}`, it works well.

However, if I assign `x@y.z` to `{username}`, client will get `406 Not Acceptable` error, the request can be received and no error happened on service side.

That means:

`http://127.0.0.1:9000/users/x@y.a`  Good

`http://127.0.0.1:9000/users/x@y.com`   Good

`http://127.0.0.1:9000/users/x@y.z` Error(406 Not Acceptable on client side)

Could anyone help to explain why `x@y.a` and `x@y.com` can work but `x@y.z` can't?

Thanks.

---

Please find controller as below.

```
@RequestMapping("/users/{login}")
public UserProfile getUserProfile(@PathVariable("login") String login) {
    log.info(String.format("Get user profile by login %s", login));
    UserProfile userProfile = userProfileRepo.getUserProfile(login);

    if (userProfile == null) {
        log.info(String.format("User profile is null for user %s", login));
        userProfile = new UserProfile();
        userProfile.setLogin(login);
        userProfileRepo.save(userProfile);
        return new UserProfile();
    }

    return userProfile;
}
```

---

A useful finding, the only log shows that `x@y.z` was truncated  as `x@y`:

```
User profile is null for user x@y
```

At the same time, if I move the path variable from @PathVariable to @RequestParam, it works.

So when assigned PathVariable {username} to `x@y.z`, only `x@y` can be assigned, who know why?

Comment: Let's see your MVC configuration.

Comment: What I using is spring-boot, and spring-mvc is auto-configured, please find it [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration).

Comment: No, I want you to post your `@Controller` and your configuration in your question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  Does embed tomcat deny the .z-suffix? If yes, do you know why service received and processed the request?

Comment: Check out `ContentNegotiatingStrategy` and `ContentNegotationManager`.